# mySQL delete based on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, natural-join

In mySQL I have two tables (course and section) and I want to delete all sections that are 1 credit and on Mondays. The course table has the credits for the course and the section table has the days for that section of the course. Here's what I have for my query but I get errors:

```
DELETE FROM
    section
WHERE
    course_ID
IN (
    SELECT course_ID
    FROM course
    NATURAL JOIN section
    WHERE credits = '1'
    AND days LIKE '%M%'
);
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what mean " but I get errors:" ?  show us the exact error message  ..

Comment: What are the actual columns that are in common between both tables?

Answer (score 1):

YOu probably don't need to reopen `section` in the subquery.  I suspect that you could phrase the query as:

```
delete s
from section s
natural join course c
where c.credit = 1 and c.days like '%M%'
```

I am not a big fan of `natural join`s, because it is not explicit about the joining logic (and depends on matching column names rather than actual schema dependencies, such as foreign keys). I would recommend switching to a regular join, maybe using the `using()` clause.

If there may be multiple rows in `course` that match on a a given `section`, then  `exists` is more appropriate than a `join`. Assuming that column `section_id` can be used to relate the two tables, you would do:

```
delete s
from section s
where exists (
    select 1
    from course c
    where c.credit = 1 and c.days like '%M%' and c.section_id = s.section_id
)
```

Comment: I used your second solution but I'm getting "0 rows affected" where there should be a lot of rows that should be deleted.

Comment: @greenguy: you might need to check the correlation condition between the two tables. I asumed `section_id` but that's jut a guess.

Comment: I need to use natural join so I'm going to try to base it off of natural join statement.

Answer (score 0):

could you have a same table exception for table section

for avoid this so you could try using a join on a subquery instead of IN clause

```
DELETE s 
FROM section s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT course_ID
    FROM course
    NATURAL JOIN section
    WHERE credits = '1'
    AND days LIKE '%M%'

) t  on t.course_ID = s.course_ID
```